# Como mostrar un documento de Word en un QTextEdit sin perder el formato

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy trabajando con documentos de Word utilizando la librería `docx`, el problema es que el documento no se muestra con el formato que está escrito, es decir, este sería el documento original mostrador en word:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este sería el resultado leyendo el documento con la librería `docx`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver no se muestra el texto con el formato que debería.

Este es el codigo que utilizo :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QTextEdit
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import docx


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)


        documento = docx.Document("Documento.docx")
        fultext = []
        for parrafo in documento.paragraphs:
            fultext.append(parrafo.text)

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.textEdit.resize(400,400)
        self.textEdit.setText('n'.join(fultext))


app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.resize(800,600)
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Los paragraphs son texto plano por lo que no podras mantener formatos, te recomiendo buscar alguna libreria que convierta docx a html y cargar ese HTML ya que este si soporta texto enriquecido. Por otro lado a mi me parece que debes cambiar `self.textEdit.setText('n'.join(fultext))` a `self.textEdit.setText('\n'.join(fultext))`

Comment: @eyllanesc, podria hacer uso de algo como esto: 
    f = QFile("path/to/your/htmlfile")
    f.open(QFile.ReadOnly|QFile.Text)
    istream = QTextStream(f)
    textfield.setHtml(istream.readAll())
    f.close()

Comment: Si ya has convertido el .docx a .html entonces seria como leer cualquier html